# Not able to get data using Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I am new to `Jsoup` and learning it
I wanted to extract rating from Imdb site/particular movie link and found that I will be able to get that from div with class = `star-box-details` and thus I wrote the following code :

```
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    try {
        Elements data;
        String userAgent = "ExampleBot 1.0 (+http://example.com/bot)";
        String url = "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0114746/";
        data =  Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent(userAgent).get().select("div.star-box-details").select("[href]");
        System.out.println(data);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

It is really strange that I get no data as I was able to get ratings data using this few weeks back. And yes div with class = `star-box-details` is present on the page/url.

Answer (score 1):

That particular user agent is probably filtered by the site preventing content from being returned. You could use

```
String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6";
```

Comment: Yes it did work ! But I am unable to understand why. I even tried without using any useragent i.e. `Jsoup.connect(url).get().select("div.star-box-details").select("[href]")` but that did not work too. Thanks

Comment: sites have policies, based on which device, which IP, etc. come to the site. And dont forget to read policies and robot files, to not get blacklisted

Comment: @cruxioneffux that site probably doesnt return data in the case where no user agent has been set. This could be as a result of a recent policy update on the site. Interestingly the whole document is empty for `ExampleBot`...

Comment: @Reimeus : Interesting now even solution you proposed has stopped working. It works just one time for one class. What to do now ?

Comment: @Reimeus : no data received as happening earlier

Comment: @cruxioneffux "now even solution you proposed has stopped working" is it possible that site temporary banned your IP (since it was involved with some suspicious actions caused by incorrect user-agent). Are you able to visit that site via browser?

Comment: @Pshemo : yes I am able to visit link/site via browser. Additionally when I change the user-agent to some other it works 2/3 times then again the data retrieval stops working. This was not happening few weeks back. I was able to retrieve data multiple times using just the example bot.Weird.

Comment: @cruxioneffux Sites can change their policy about non-browser clients if they take too much resources needed to handle requests from browser clients (I am not saying that it happened here but it is possibility). So if you are visiting that site too often you may be blocked. Try to visit it every 2-5 minutes.

Comment: Try to simulate a "real" browser with your code - add all the fields that your browser sends to the site - host, encoding etc.

Comment: @Pshemo : thanks yes I think its a site only thing as google searches seem to be fine using any agent.